# Checking if Wi-Fi is available but internet isn't on iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, reachability

I have this very weird case right now with an app I'm working on. The Wi-Fi network I'm testing it on has no internet enabled, yet it still shows that I have a conexión when using `Reachability`. How can I check for this case so I can tell the user there is no connection available?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `reachabilityWithHostName` (I presume you are using `reachabilityForInternetConnection` or `reachabilityForLocalWiFi`) to check if you can reach a particular external hostname.

For example, this code will return YES if there is no internet connection:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
if ([reachability currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable)
     return YES;
```

Comment: @8vius - Interested to know if this helped..?

Comment: Haven't been home to give it a try, but sounds like it would work, thank you.

Comment: Actually I'm suspecting it won't help. What Reachability actually does and what people think it does is pretty confusing. Your results could help clarify for me.

Answer (score 0):

Define 'connection', there are several layers of connections that are key to getting working Internet service via Wi-Fi:

- Layer 1 (Physical Link) is the radio in range?
- Layer 2 (MAC) see above for the most part, but conflicting MAC addresses can cause issues
- Layer 3 (IP) did we get an IP address from DHCP/BOOTP or Static configuration?
- Layer 3 (GW) can we reach the gateway?
- Layer 3 (ROUTE) can we reach the next-hop router?
- Layer 7 (DNS) can we reach the DNS servers? Are we being spoofed or captivated?

Once all those things are working, you should have 'working Wi-Fi'